# Удаление ненужных элементов из списка

Tags: python, списки

Добрый день!
Пишу скрипт, который мониторит неиспользуемые порты на коммутаторе.
После некоторой обработки список выглядит так:

```
['Fa1/0/6", 'Fa1/0/18', 'Fa1/0/20', 'Fa1/0/36', 'Fa2/0/23', 'Fa3/0/38', 'Fa3/0/41', 'Gi1/0/1', 'Gi1/0/2', 'Gi1/0/3', 'Gi1/0/4', 'Gi2/0/1', 'Gi2/0/2']
```

Необходимо, удалить все элементы, которые не начинаются на `Fa`, т.е. оставить в списке только это:

```
'Fa1/0/6", 'Fa1/0/18', 'Fa1/0/20', 'Fa1/0/36', 'Fa2/0/23', 'Fa3/0/38', 'Fa3/0/41'
```

В программировании слаб, но хочется реализовать. Спасибо!

Comment: В лоб: проходите по списку, смотрите с чего начинается элемент. Нужные пишете в новый список.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вот так сделать:

```
>>> data = ['Fa1/0/6', 'Fa1/0/18', 'Fa1/0/20', 'Fa1/0/36', 'Fa2/0/23', 'Fa3/0/38', 'Fa3/0/41', 'Gi1/0/1', 'Gi1/0/2', 'Gi1/0/3', 'Gi1/0/4', 'Gi2/0/1', 'Gi2/0/2']
>>> fdata = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('Fa'), data))
>>> fdata
['Fa1/0/6', 'Fa1/0/18', 'Fa1/0/20', 'Fa1/0/36', 'Fa2/0/23', 'Fa3/0/38', 'Fa3/0/41']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a=['Fa1/0/6', 'Fa1/0/18', 'Fa1/0/20', 'Fa1/0/36', 'Fa2/0/23', 'Fa3/0/38', 'Fa3/0/41', 'Gi1/0/1', 'Gi1/0/2', 'Gi1/0/3', 'Gi1/0/4', 'Gi2/0/1', 'Gi2/0/2']
[x for x in a if x.startswith("Fa")]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну, раз стандартные питоничьи алгоритмы уже написали, то добавлю старенький стандартный вариант с циклом:

```
data = ['Fa1/0/6', 'Fa1/0/18', 'Fa1/0/20', 'Fa1/0/36', 'Fa2/0/23', 'Fa3/0/38', 'Fa3/0/41', 'Gi1/0/1', 'Gi1/0/2', 'Gi1/0/3', 'Gi1/0/4', 'Gi2/0/1', 'Gi2/0/2']
fdata = []

for x in data:
    if x.startswith('Fa'):
        fdata.append(x)

print(fdata)
```

И кое-что из регулярок:

```
import re

data = ['Fa1/0/6', 'Fa1/0/18', 'Fa1/0/20', 'Fa1/0/36', 'Fa2/0/23', 'Fa3/0/38', 'Fa3/0/41', 'Gi1/0/1', 'Gi1/0/2', 'Gi1/0/3', 'Gi1/0/4', 'Gi2/0/1', 'Gi2/0/2']
text_data = ''.join(data)

fdata = re.findall(r'Fa\d+/\d+/\d+', text_data)
print(fdata)
```

Консоль:

```
['Fa1/0/6', 'Fa1/0/18', 'Fa1/0/20', 'Fa1/0/36', 'Fa2/0/23', 'Fa3/0/38', 'Fa3/0/41']
```